# PageNavi for wordpress stuck on the first page

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a problem with WP-PageNavi and some code that builds a page that has two columns of different category posts. PageNavi seems to get stuck on the first page of these posts, I think it might have something to do with the permalink structure but I'm not sure how to get around the problem.

code at http://pastebin.com/VrhEWyvp

Thanks

Comment: The code from this pastebin link is gone.  Do you think you could put it into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query in this line:

```
<div class="box"><?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?><?php $hol = 1; ?>
```

is missing the pagination parameter:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

try:

```
<div class="box"><?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : (get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1 ); query_posts('showposts=5&paged=' . $paged); ?><?php $hol = 1; ?>
```

(this may look a bit complicated, but simply provides for either 'paged' or 'page' in the link of paginated pages)

Answered by alchymyth over at wordpress